# Separate ul li CSS

Tags: html, css

Is possible separate 2 ul? I need 2x ul:

first is used for horizontal menu and connected with CSS,
second I want UL but not affected by CSS, only UL without changes

So basically how to don't use CSS in next UL?

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class to the `ul` you want to style with CSS.

```
<ul class="first">
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
...
...
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

And the css is

```
ul.first{
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```